# python subprocess does not capture stderr of a pv command

Tags: python, subprocess, stderr, pv

I need to run some bash script with python and show the output. Some of these scripts contains some `pv` command but from `subprocess` I am not able to get the `pv` output.

```py
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(["./script.sh"], shell=False, bufsize=1, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

p.wait()

print(p.returncode)
print(p.stdout.read())
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "aaa"
echo "bbb" >&2

pv -L 1000 -F "%t %b %r %e" /path/to/some/file | cat > /tmp/foo
```

Runnig this python script I simply get `echo`'s outputs:

```
$ python script.py 
0
aaa
bbb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pv` is sensitive to whether it is running in a terminal. If you want to capture its output, use the `pv -f` option to force it to display the progress indicator even when it's not connected to a terminal.

For more complex scenarios, you might have to use something like `pty` to simulate running under a terminal.

(Of course, you might be better off using a native Python progress bar like [`tqdm`](https://tqdm.github.io/).)

Comment: Thanks, using `pty` I can make it work but my use case is pretty complex (multiple scripts to run in parallel) and using `pty` became difficult. Anyway I found that `pv` has a `-f` flag that:
"_Force output. Normally, pv will not output any visual display if standard error is not a terminal. This option forces it to do so._"
and this solves my problem

Comment: Oh good, I'll add that to the answer. I meant to check but got distracted.